# How can i get text between <span> </span>using python splinter lib

Tags: python, web-scraping, html, splinter

I want get the text between 
I have already use lib splinter

```
"<span id="stWelcomeInbox" class="nui-txt-impt">
1
</span>"
```

PS: i don't want to download the page and read as html code
maybe re lib is available but i don't know how to use it without download that page.i don't know how to use re lib ,too. please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`find_by_id()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_id) method:

```
element = browser.find_by_id('stWelcomeInbox').first
print element.text
```